# Find the set of $z\in \mathbb{C}$ that satisfies $|z| >1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm stuck with this complex numbers exercise, which is probably not too complicated to solve but I'm not sure how to do it.
The exercise is the one I stated in the title, with $z=a+bi$.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you write $|z|$ in terms of $a$ and $b$? If so you can express your set that way.

Comment: You mean to write it like this $\sqrt{a^{2} +b^{2}}  >1$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That’s one of very many equivalent ways to express $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|>1\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z=a+ bi$ multiply by its conjugate

$|z|^2 = a^2 + b^2$ equation of a circle around the origin with "radius" $a^2 + b^2$

$|z|^2 > 1$ take the root

$|z| > 1$ describes all points outside the unitary circle in the Gauss plane

$z = a + bi$ means that you represent the field of complex numbers as 2-dimensional vector space, (sometimes called the Gauss plane), and to the norm of any complex number $z$ can be associated a circle around the origin in in the $(a, b)$-plane